# How to build a list using a Map?

Tags: list, dictionary, ocaml

First of all, I have those types :

```
type position = float * float

type node = position
```

To build my Map I've written those modules :

```
module MyMap =
  struct
    type t = Graph.node
    let compare (a1,b1) (a2,b2) =
      if a1 > a2 then 1
       else if a1 < a2 then -1
       else if b1 > b2 then 1
       else if b1 < b2 then -1
       else 0
  end

module DistMap = Map.Make(MyMap)
```

In my case, I'll have a `previousMap` that has type `val previousMap : (float * float) DistMap.t = <abstr>` 
It contains nodes as key, and values. 
Let's say it is built like this :

```
DistMap.bindings prevMap;;
- : (node * (float * float)) list =
[((1., 1.), (2., 2.)); 
((2., 2.), (3., 3.)); 
((3., 3.), (4., 4.));
((4., 4.), (5., 5.))]
```

It means that (2.,2.) is the predecessor node of (1.,1.) in a graph.

What I am aiming for is to build the list that represent the path from a `source` node to a `target` node.

For example, if I had :

```
let build_path prevMap source target
```

The expected output using the `previousMap` would be a `node (or float * float) list` like this :

```
build_path previousMap (1.,1.) (5.,5.) -> [(1.,1.);(2.,2.);(3.,3.);(4.,4.);(5.,5.)]
```

So far my attempts consisted in trying to use the `fold` and `iter` function on the `previousMap` but they were inconclusive.

**Update :**

Here's an attempt I think could be close to what I want to achieve :

```
let build_list map source target =
  let rec build_aux acc map source x =
    if ((DistMap.find x map)) = source then source::acc
    else build_aux (DistMap.find x map)::acc source (DistMap.find x map)
    in build_aux [] map source target
```

However I get this error output :

```
356 |     else build_aux (DistMap.find x map)::acc source (DistMap.find x map)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         'a list
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

**Update 2 :**

The issue has been solved, however the function isn't behaving as expected. Basically this is the pseudo-code I'd like to implement :

[image: pseudo-code]

How could I proceed to build such a list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `fold` and `iter` is that they process nodes in an order that they determine themselves. In essence the order is based on the shape of the map, which is determined by the keys. You want to process the nodes of the map in an order determined by the values in the map.

I'm pretty sure the only way to proceed is to write your own special-purpose recursive function.

**Update**

In the latest code you have this expression:

```
build_aux (DistMap.find x map)::acc source (DistMap.find x map)
```

The operator precedence in OCaml that binds function arguments to functions is very tight, so this gets parsed like this:

```
(build_aux (DistMap.find x map)) :: (acc source (DistMap.find x map))
```

You need parentheses around this subexpression:

```
((DistMap.find x map)::acc)
```

Comment: This is what I've tried recently : ```let build_list map source target =
  let rec build_aux acc map source x =
    if ((DistMap.find x map)) = source then source::acc
    else build_aux (DistMap.find x map)::acc source (DistMap.find x map)
    in build_aux [] map source target```
However this is the error output I get : ```Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'a list
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list```
I think I might be on the good path, but I honestly don't know how to resolve this issue. I just append an element to an accumulator here.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. However when the function is actually used on the example of the post, it raises a ```Not_found``` exception. I believe it does because at the end when I get to the ```source``` node, there's no predecessor for the ```source``` node. I'd like to use a ```try``` instead of the ```if``` but I wouldn't know how to get to the ```else``` branch.